# how to update the value of dictionary in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have:

```
new_dict['a1']['Road_Type']=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a2']['Road_Type']=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a3']['Road_Type']=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a4']['Road_Type']=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Now after updating I want it to be:

```
new_dict['a1']['Road_Type']=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a2']['Road_Type']=[5,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a3']['Road_Type']=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a4']['Road_Type']=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

My code:

```
kk=new_dict['a2']['Road_Type']
kk[0]=5
new_dict['a2']['Road_Type']=kk
```

but the result is:

```
new_dict['a1']['Road_Type']=[5,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a2']['Road_Type']=[5,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a3']['Road_Type']=[5,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict['a4']['Road_Type']=[5,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

all value are getting updated, so how can I update particular value.

Comment: Please show the code where the inner list is created and assigned to the dictionary. Because it looks like you are storing a reference to the same list multiple times.

Comment: I want to change it in ['a2'] only @OmarEinea

Comment: @dhke inner list is like list=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and then through loop I assign them like new_dict[p]['Road_Type]=list

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments on your question, you are making a mistake due to not knowing how Python works. I'll make it simpler in example, but this also stands for your case when you have `new_dict[a][b]...[n]`.

Here is how you probably are generating your dictionary:

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
new_dict = []
for p in range(N):
    new_dict[p] = lst
```

This however binds every `new_dict[p]`, for `p=0,...,N` to the same `lst`, i.e. each `new_dict[p]` value references the same instance of `list`.

You have to generate new list for each `new_dict[p]`.

Here is how you should generate it:

```
new_dict = {}

for p in range(N):
    new_dict[p] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

After your dictionary is populated, you can edit it with one line:

```
new_dict['a1']['RoadType'][0] = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update `a2` separately:

```
new_dict = {
    'a1': {'Road_Type': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
    'a2': {'Road_Type': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
    'a3': {'Road_Type': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
    'a4': {'Road_Type': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
}

new_dict['a2']['Road_Type'][0] = 5

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'a1': {'Road_Type': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, 
 'a2': {'Road_Type': [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, 
 'a3': {'Road_Type': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, 
 'a4': {'Road_Type': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}
```

Comment: att = ['Road_Type','Speed_limit','Junction_Detail','Junction_Control']  
dd=pd.read_csv('finalstring.csv')
r=dd['Police_Force']
my_set=set()
ll=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
new_dict={}
for i in r:
    my_set.add(i)
    new_dict[i]={}
    for j in att:
        new_dict[i][j]=ll
new_dict['a5']['Road_Type'][0]=5
print(new_dict)                                                                                        still showing the same result

Comment: Try `new_dict[i]={} 
for j in att:
    new_dict[i][j]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ` instead. Hard to tell whats going on here since I don't know what `finalstring.csv` looks like.

Comment: your comment worked thanks a lot.Can I know why my code didn't work?

Comment: @SudhanshuBhandarwar You were setting each dictionary key to the same object `l1`. So each key was referencing the same object. Whenever one gets updated, they all get updated. If you instead set each key to `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` on each iteration, they are all referencing different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :
There is a small mistake in your code ,you update the index 0 of 'a2' and then  assign the 'kk' that point the new_dict of 'a2'

**Program :**

```
new_dict = {}
new_dict['a1']= {'Road_Type': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
new_dict['a2']= {'Road_Type': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
new_dict['a3']= {'Road_Type': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
new_dict['a4']= {'Road_Type': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}


kk=new_dict['a2']['Road_Type']
kk[0]=5

print(new_dict)
```

**Output :**

```
{'a2': {'Road_Type': [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, 
 'a3': {'Road_Type': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
 'a4': {'Road_Type': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
 'a1': {'Road_Type': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}
```